# Int to bool with ternary operator

Tags: arrays, ternary-operator

There is a method for counting the equal numbers in an ascending array:

```
public void CheckArr (int [] array)
{
    int count = 0;
    int prev = array [0];
    bool inPair = false;

    for (int i = 1; i <array.Length; i ++)
    {
        if (array [i] == prev)
        {
            count + = inPair? 1:2;
            inPair = true;
        }
        else
        {
            prev = array [i];
            inPair = false;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine (count);
}
```

I can not understand the expression: `count + = inPair? 1:2;`
How does int equate to bool? What does it look like if you rewrite it to if / else?

Comment: _"Enter the code here"_? Really?

Answer (score 1):

When you write an expression like

```
count += inPair? 1:2;
```

Its like writing it like this:

```
if (inPair) {
  count += 1;
} else {
  count += 2;
}
```

It doesn't make int equal to bool it makes count equal to 1 if the bool is true and equal to 2 if you boolean is false in your example.

Comment: No need for `(brackets)` in Swift